# VBA: Query With Excel Tables as the Datasource

Tags: sql, excel, excel-2007, connection-string, vba

I want to query the table, which consists of a named range, from VBA using SQL.

```
name id
Alpha 1
Beta 2
Gamma 3
```

I want to perform a query like, `select Name from table1 where id =3` in VBA

Can someone help with the connection string that needs to be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This puts it pretty well: 
http://vbadud.blogspot.com/2007/12/query-table-with-excel-as-data-source.html